# Can I filter a SharePoint Calendar? Is such a thing possible?

Tags: filter, sharepoint-calendar

It strange that for something that sounds so simple and common, it is most likely impossible. When I first approached this request I never thought I'd end up here typing out my problem ...

I added a calendar web part to my SharePoint 2010 page. Out of the box it works fine and does what it's designed to do.

I would like to be able to filter the calendar based on what a users selects in a drop down or enters into a text box. When they hit enter or press a button some sort of filtering action should occur, such as calendar events are returned, or parts of the calendar are highlighted, or something similar.

Is there any simple, straight forward way to do this? I'd prefer not to start writing PowerShell scripts or C# classes.

Also, if someone is certain that this is just simply not possible please let me know. I don't want to chase after something that is not possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since a calendar is a list, a very simple OOTB solution is to use the `SharePoint List Filter` web part and connect it to a column in your calendar for a user to filter on. For example, filter by an event type, etc.

There are also text filters available, but OOTB not very useful. There are several articles online that have step-by-step instructions for how to create a fairly simple text filter that doesn't need to match an entire field exactly. Again, you'll need to connect the filter to one or more columns in your list to filter on. Here are a couple of articles to get started:

[THE TEXT FILTER WEB PART – WITHOUT HAVING TO FILTER EXACT TEXT](https://wonderlaura.com/2010/07/02/the-text-filter-web-part-without-having-to-filter-exact-text/comment-page-1/)

[SharePoint 2010 Search list using OOTB Text filter Web Part](http://SharePoint%202010%20Search%20list%20using%20OOTB%20Text%20filter%20Web%20Part)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way it can be done using "calculated columns" and some Jquery and HTML.

The following article explains how to do it for SharePoint Online for Office 365, I have also used it for SharePoint 2013 on-premise and I would imagine it could be used for SharePoint 2010 as well but may need some slight tweaking to get it to work.

[Calendar filtering for SharePoint](https://crm.webfletch.co.uk/posts/sharepoint-calendar-filter-resource-on-a-single-calendar-office-365)